# How to validate cascading dropdown in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I am developing a MVC application and I am using Cascading dropdown in one of my dropdown. The problem is I need to validate both drop downs if user has not selected any value. Currently its validating both drop downs when you clicks on save after immediate opening of pop up, but when you selects value from master drop down(Company) and selects value from Child drop down(Customer) and again change value of master drop down the child drop down is not validating.

Here I am providing code of my Model, View and Controller file.

Model-

```
public class CustomerComment : BaseModel
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Customer name")]
        public int InvoiceCustomerId { get; set; }


        public string OldCustomerId { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Invoice Customer")]
        public string  InvoiceCustomerName { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Invoice Customer")]
        public string InvoiceCustomer { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Company name")]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Company name")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }


        public string  Company { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = " Comment")]
        [StringLength(220, ErrorMessage = "Customer comment must be maximum length of 220")]
        public string Comment { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Group")]
        public bool Group { get; set; }

        public List<InvoiceCustomer> InvoiceCustomerList { get; set; }


        public CustomerComment()
        {
            InvoiceCustomerList = new List<InvoiceCustomer>();            
        }
}
```

View:

```
@model ACS.MDB.Net.App.Models.CustomerComment

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MDB::Customer Comment";    
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<div style="background: #F9F7FB">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)        

        //hidden field                
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)        
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.InvoiceCustomerId, new { @id = "txtCustomerId" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CompanyId, new { @id = "txtCompanyId" }) 
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.InvoiceCustomerName, new { @id = "txtCustomerName" }) 
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CompanyName, new { @id = "txtCompanyName" })            


        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            @if (Model.ID != 0)
            {    
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CompanyName, new { style = "width:300px" })</b>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
            }
            else
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyName, new { @class = "mandatoryLabel" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CompanyId, new SelectList(Model.OAcompanyList, "ID", "Name", Model.CompanyId), "Select Company", new { @id = "ddlCompany", style = "width:300px;height:25px" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyId)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            @if (Model.ID != 0)
            {    
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.InvoiceCustomerName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.InvoiceCustomerName, new { style = "width:300px" })</b>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
            }
            else
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceCustomerName, new { @class = "mandatoryLabel" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.InvoiceCustomerId, new SelectList(Model.InvoiceCustomerList, "ID", "CustomerandOACustomerId", Model.InvoiceCustomerId), "Select Customer", new { @id = "ddlInvCustomer", style = "width:300px;height:25px" })
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceCustomerId)
                </td>
            </tr>
            }

            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Comment)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Comment, 4, 1, new { @id = "txtCustomerComment", @maxlength = "220", style = "width:290px; resize: none" })
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment)
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Group, new { style = "width:200px" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Group)

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </table>           
    }

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    SetFocus('#ddlCompany');
    DisableInvalidKeyForControl('#txtCustomerComment');

    if ('@Model.ID' > 0)
    {
        SetFocus('#txtCustomerComment');
    }

    var selectedCustomerId = -1;
    var selectedCompanyId = -1;
    var selectedCustomerName = '';
    var selectedCompanyName = '';


    $("#ddlCompany").change(function () {
        //var selectedCustomerId = -1;
        selectedCompanyId = $(this).val();;
        selectedCompanyName = $(this).children('option').filter(':selected').text();
        $("#txtCompanyId").val(selectedCompanyId);
        $("#txtCompanyName").val(selectedCompanyName);        


        if (selectedCompanyId != -1 && selectedCompanyId != 0) {

            var postData = { companyId: selectedCompanyId };
            //Get InvoiceCustomerList based on selected company id
            $.post("/Contract/GetInvoiceCustomerListByCompany", postData, function (response) {

                if (response != null) {
                    $("#ddlInvCustomer").empty();                    
                    $("#ddlInvCustomer").length = -1;
                    AddOption("Select Customer", "-1", "#ddlInvCustomer");
                    for (var i in response) {
                        AddOption(response[i].CustomerandOACustomerId, response[i].InvoiceCustomerId, "#ddlInvCustomer");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#ddlInvCustomer").empty();
            selectedCompanyId = 0;
            selectedCustomerId = 0;
            $("#ddlInvCustomer").val = 0;
            AddOption("Select Customer", "0", "#ddlInvCustomer");
        }
    })

    $("#ddlInvCustomer").change(function () {
        selectedCustomerId = $(this).val();
        selectedCustomerName = $(this).children('option').filter(':selected').text();
        if (selectedCustomerId != -1 && selectedCustomerId != 0) {

            $("#txtCustomerId").val(selectedCustomerId);
            $("#txtCustomerName").val(selectedCustomerName);            
        }
        //else {            
        //    $("#ddlInvCustomer").empty();
        //    selectedCustomerId = 0;            
        //    $("#ddlInvCustomer").val = 0;
        //    AddOption("Select Customer", "0");
        //}
    })

    //Disable Save button of pop up for viewer
    DisableSaveButton();

</script>
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ACS.MDB.Net.App.Common;
using ACS.MDB.Net.App.Models;
using ACS.MDB.Net.App.Services;
using ACS.MDB.Net.App.ValueObjects;
using MODEL = ACS.MDB.Net.App.Models;

namespace ACS.MDB.Net.App.Controllers
{
    public partial class ContractController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns CustomerComment index view
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>CustomerComment index view</returns>        
        /// GET: /ContractController/CustomerComment/
        public ActionResult CustomerCommentIndex()
        {
            return IndexView();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the customer comment list
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="param"></param>
        /// <returns>Customer comment List</returns>
        public ActionResult CustomerCommentList(MODEL.jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
        {
            try
            {
                List<Company> companyList = Session.GetUserAssociatedCompanyList();
                List<CompanyVO> companyVOList = new List<CompanyVO>();
                foreach (var item in companyList)
                {
                    companyVOList.Add(new CompanyVO(item));
                }

                CustomerCommentService customerCommentService = new CustomerCommentService();
                List<MODEL.CustomerComment> customerCommentList = new List<CustomerComment>();

                List<CustomerCommentVO> customerCommentVOList = customerCommentService.GetCustomerCommentList(companyVOList);

                foreach (var item in customerCommentVOList)
                {
                    customerCommentList.Add(new MODEL.CustomerComment(item));
                }

                //get the field on with sorting needs to happen and set the
                //ordering function/delegate accordingly.
                int sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);
                var orderingFunction = GetCustomerCommentOrderingFunction(sortColumnIndex);

                var result = GetFilteredObjects(param, customerCommentList, orderingFunction);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeAndErrorResult(500, e.Message);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create new customer comment
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The Customer comment details view</returns>
        public ActionResult CustomerCommentCreate()
        {
            try
            {
                MODEL.CustomerComment customerComment = new MODEL.CustomerComment();

                customerComment.OAcompanyList = Session.GetUserAssociatedCompanyList();                
                return PartialView("CustomerCommentDetails", customerComment);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeAndErrorResult(500, e.Message);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Edit customer comment
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The customer comment id</param>
        /// <returns>Customer comment details</returns>
        public ActionResult CustomerCommentEdit(int id)
        {
            MODEL.CustomerComment customercomment = new CustomerComment();
            try
            {
                CustomerCommentService customerCommentService = new CustomerCommentService();

                //Get Customercomment details                
                CustomerCommentVO customerCommentVO = customerCommentService.GetCustomerCommentById(id);
                if (customerCommentVO == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format(Constants.ITEM_NOT_FOUND, Constants.CUSTOMERCOMMENT));
                }
                else
                {
                    customercomment = new CustomerComment(customerCommentVO);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
            }
            return PartialView("CustomerCommentDetails", customercomment);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Save the customer comment
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model">model object</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public ActionResult CustomerCommentSave(MODEL.CustomerComment model)
        {
                try
                {
                    if (model.InvoiceCustomerId == 0)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("Please select Customer name");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        CustomerCommentService customerCommentService = new CustomerCommentService();

                        if (ModelState.IsValid)
                        {
                            //Get user id
                            int? userId = Session.GetUserId();
                            if (userId.HasValue)
                            {
                                CustomerCommentVO customerCommentVO = new CustomerCommentVO(model, userId);
                                customerCommentService.SaveCustomerComment(customerCommentVO);
                            }
                            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new ApplicationException(String.Format(Constants.CANNOT_SAVE, Constants.CUSTOMERCOMMENT));
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (ApplicationException e)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeAndErrorResult(500, e.Message);
                }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Delete the Customer comment(s)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Ids">Ids of customerComment to be deleted</param>
        public ActionResult CustomerCommentDelete(List<int> ids)
        {
            try
            {
                CustomerCommentService customerCommentService = new CustomerCommentService();
                customerCommentService.DeleteCustomerComment(ids);
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeAndErrorResult(500, e.Message);
            }
        }

        /////// <summary>
        /////// Gets the Customer List
        /////// </summary>
        /////// <returns>Invoice Customer List</returns>
        //public List<MODEL.InvoiceCustomer> GetCustomerList()
        //{
        //    MODEL.CustomerComment customerComment = new CustomerComment();
        //    InvoiceCustomerService invoiceCustomerService = new InvoiceCustomerService();
        //    List<InvoiceCustomerVO> invoiceCustomerVOList = invoiceCustomerService.GetAllCustomerList();

        //    foreach (InvoiceCustomerVO item in invoiceCustomerVOList)
        //    {
        //        customerComment.InvoiceCustomerList.Add(new MODEL.InvoiceCustomer(item));
        //    }

        //    return customerComment.InvoiceCustomerList;
        //}


        ///// <summary>
        ///// Gets invoice customer list based on customer name
        ///// </summary>
        ///// <param name="customerName">customer name</param>
        ///// <returns>Invoice customer List</returns>
        //public JsonResult GetCompanyByCustomerName(string customerName)
        //{
        //    try
        //    {
        //        InvoiceCustomerService invoiceCustomerService = new InvoiceCustomerService();
        //        List<CompanyVO> companyVOList = invoiceCustomerService.GetCompanyListByCustomerName(customerName);
        //        //List<InvoiceCustomerVO> invoiceCustomerVOList = invoiceCustomerService.GetCompanyByCustomerName(customerName);

        //        return Json(companyVOList);
        //    }
        //    catch (Exception e)
        //    {
        //        return Json(new ApplicationException());

        //    }
        //}

        /// <summary>
        /// Get InvoiceCustomer List based on companyId
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="companyId">company Id</param>
        /// <returns>Invoice customer List based on company Id</returns>
        public JsonResult GetInvoiceCustomerListByCompany(int companyId)
        {
            try
            {
                InvoiceCustomerService invoiceCustomerService = new InvoiceCustomerService();
                List<InvoiceCustomerVO> invoiceCustomerVOList = invoiceCustomerService.GetInvoiceCustomerList(companyId);

                return Json(invoiceCustomerVOList);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(new ApplicationException());

            }
        }


        /// The function used to return field used for sorting
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sortCol">The column number on which sorting needs to happen</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Func<BaseModel, object> GetCustomerCommentOrderingFunction(int sortCol)
        {
            Func<BaseModel, object> sortFunction = null;
            switch (sortCol)
            {
                case 2:
                    sortFunction = obj => ((MODEL.CustomerComment)obj).InvoiceCustomer;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sortFunction = obj => ((MODEL.CustomerComment)obj).Company;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    sortFunction = obj => ((MODEL.CustomerComment)obj).Comment;
                    break;
                default:
                    sortFunction = obj => ((MODEL.CustomerComment)obj).ID;
                    break;
            }

            return sortFunction;
        }
    }
}
```